# How to mock double autowired class

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

In the following case, can I test "MainServiceImpl"?

【What I want to do】

・Test target object is "MainServiceImpl".

・SubMainServiceImpl is used without mock.

・SubSubMainServiceImpl.subSubSayHello method is used with mock.

You may say "double autowired class is not recommended to mock." I know, but I want to know the above test is technically possible.

```
//Test Target Object
@Service
public class MainServiceImpl implements MainService {

  @Autowired
  private SubMainService subMainService;

  @Override
  public String mainSayHello() {
    return "MainSayHello. Also..." + subMainService.subSayHello();
  }
}
```

```
//MainServiceImpl depends on this class.
@Service
public class SubMainServiceImpl implements SubMainService {

  @Autowired
  private SubSubMainService subSubMainService;

  @Override
  public String subSayHello() {
    return "SubSayHello. Also..." + subSubMainService.subSubSayHello();
  }
}
```

```
//SubSubServiceImpl depends on this class.
@Service
public class SubSubMainServiceImpl implements SubSubMainService {

  @Override
  public String subSubSayHello() {
      return "SubSubSayHello";
    }
}
```

As a side note, I can mock direct-autowired class.
How can I mock "double" autowired class?

```
//Direct(not double) autowired class is mocked.
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MockMainServiceTest {

  @InjectMocks
  MainServiceImpl mainService;

  @Mock
  SubMainService subMainService;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void SubMainService_Mocked(){
    doReturn("SubMainService_Mocked").when(subMainService).subSayHello();
    Assert.assertThat(mainService.mainSayHello() ,is("MainSayHello. Also...SubMainService_Mocked"));
  }
}
```

Technology
SpringBoot 2.5.4
JUnit 4.2
Java 1.8

Comment: Your test doesn't make sense. Either use Spring Boot for testing or mocking, you are using both at the same time. Just `@Autowire` `MainServiceImpl` (or better `MainService` the interface). Then ditch the `subMainService` field and your `setup` method. Add an field of type `SubSubMainService` and add `@MockBean`. This will create a full integration test, if you really want a unit test, wire the dependencies yourself (don't use Spring).

Comment: You are confused. When you inject mocks into MainService you replace subMainService with a mock and its original code is never executed. It does not and cannot call subSubMainService and you really wouldn't want it to do so anyway. Your mock is told what to return when subSayHello is called.